# R: Window Function "Start" after "End"

Tags: r

I am having a problem with the window function in `R`.

```
newdata1 <-window(mergedall,start=c(as.Date(as.character("2014-06-16"))),end=c(as.Date(as.character("2015-01-31"))))
```

I got this error. I am trying to understand how I can fix this issue. Thank you!

```
Error in window.default(mergedall, start = c(as.Date(as.character("2014-06-16"))),  : 
  'start' cannot be after 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(mergedall, start = c(as.Date(as.character("2014-06-16"))),  :
  'end' value not changed`
```

Comment: Take off the combine `c` function. Just use `newdata1 <-window(mergedall,start=as.Date(as.character("2014-06-16")),end=as.Date(as.character("2015-01-31")))`

Comment: Hi RP, I took off the c function but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post. But, please make sure that "mergedall" is a time series object which was created using the ts command.

While creating the time series object from any vector or series,

```
some_result_ts <- ts(vector,frequency=xx,start=c(yyyy,m))
```

This kind of error comes when yyyy is lesser than the start you are specifying in window command.

For example if you take a data frame column or a vector or series , and during the ts formation with ts command, give yyyy=2010,m=1 with a frequency of 12 and assuming it's a 36 month data, the implicit end will be 2013,12.

```
some_result_ts <- ts(vector,frequency=12,start=c(2010,1))
```

Then, while using a window function, if you are specifying let's say, start = c(2014,1) , then R will give a message that => 'start' cannot be after 'end' and end value not changed.

Answer (score 2):

Again it's an old post. But since I stumbled upon it by searching the same error. I want to still provide something useful for future Googlers.

I could not replicate your issue because you did not provide your own *mergedall* dataset. So I am starting with a toy example to show a few places where the problem might be. It's really not that difficult at all.

Potential problem #1:

You did not create a ts object to begin with. Window function operates on a ts object, and it cannot just be a vector took directly from a df. Use ts function to make a vector a ts object first. And then assign it with proper start, end, frequency.

```
all <-seq(1:8) #eight observations in sequence
```

Assign these eight values as monthly observations, starting from 201406 to 201501. Frequency 12 means monthly.

```
all.ts <- ts(all, start = c(2014,6), end = c(2015,1), frequency = 12)
```

Potential problem #2:

You perhaps already assigned your mergedall series as a ts object, but with different start/end/frequency. My example above was based on monthly observations. So even though they are correct examples, they will not match with your daily-based window function. Window function and the ts object needs to be consistent.

Following my example, the window function would look like:

```
newdata1 <-window(all.ts,start=c(2014,6),end=c(2015,1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is what you can try, perhaps this would be the solution as I also faced the same problem.

You might not be referring to proper index value in the timeseries object.

In below code I have added the index (i) you can put 1 in case the object has only one series or any number or pass different values using a simple loop.
Hope it helps.!

```
newdata1 <-window(mergedall[i],start=c(as.Date(as.character("2014-06-16"))),end=c(as.Date(as.character("2015-01-31"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also a future googler and none of the answers helped me. This was my problem and solution:

MWE issue:

```
set.seed(50)
data <- ts(rnorm(100), start(1850))
data.train <- window(data, start = 1850, end = 1949)
```

MWE solution:

```
set.seed(50)
data <- ts(rnorm(100), start = (1850))
data.train <- window(data, start = 1850, end = 1949)
```

Issue was the missing equals sign when setting the start date.
The resulting variable `data` was still a time series; but the give-away was: "Time-Series from 1 to 100" rather than "Time-Series from 1850 to 1949", which told me that *something* was awry with creating the time series.

The `ts` function doesn't raise this as an error, presumably because it accepts the `start()` function from the `{stats}` package, according to the `?ts` doc.

Answer (score 0):

`start` and `end` arguments accept row names or row numbers. If you are getting this error, check if your `ts` object has row names and if not, use row number.

See the difference between a `ts` with and without row names:

```
my_ts <- ts(1:50, frequency = 4)
my_named_ts <- ts(1:50, frequency = 4, start = c(1961,1))
```

These window calls are valid and return the same data:

```
window(my_ts, 6, 9)
window(my_named_ts, 1966, 1969)
```

Compare to these window calls that are not valid:

```
window(my_ts, 1966, 1969)
window(my_named_ts, 6, 9)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is probably an issue arising from the format of your 'mergedall' object.
Make sure that you have a ts, xts or a zoo object. 
Try f.ex. the following first, in order to ensure the format of your object:

```
str(mergedall)
```